# How do I revert CHOWN command?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, magento

I don't know I should post this on Magento community site or Ubuntu community site, so I am posting here.

I had PHP 5.3 installed.

I upgraded to PHP 5.5, but for some reasons had to revert back to PHP 5.3.

ISSUE:

I have Magento and Codeigniter website on server. From now on, whenever I try to save image from website's dashboard, either Magento or CI, I get `folder is not writeable` like error.

Then I checked online for solution and I found that Apache user should be owner, so I ran chown -R apache:apache /public_html on server. This solved images issue, I was able to save images from website's dashboard.

But there is another problem, when I checkout on my Magento website I get this  error.

[image]

Do I need to install Apache all over again? or what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Apache uses the www-data account to read html files. However, chowning to www-data is usually not a good idea; it will make it easier to do remote modifications to files in your site. Try chmod 755 to allow read access to www-data?

Comment: sorry I am not linux expert... can you please tell me which command I should run?

Comment: chmod -R 755 /path/to/apache/directory